# Configuring DB driver dependency for Slick2-based projects in SBT?

Tags: scala, sbt, slick

I have two Scala projects managed by SBT - `models_project` and `client_project`.

The `models_project` contains the DB models (Slick2-based). This project contains all the Slick tables and rows definitions. The `client_project` depends on the `models_project` to access the DB.

I want to be able to configure the driver at the `client_project` project.

The problem I'm facing is that I need to import the driver (for example `scala.slick.driver.PostgresDriver.simple._`) in the `models_project` to get many of the types that the model require.

I figured out how to configure those in a separate / independent project (so I'll have `driver_project` and both `client_project` and `models_project` will depend on it), but this requires the configuration to be made at the `driver_project` project. What I really want is for my `models_project` to be agnostic of the driver and for `client_project` to have a configuration of which driver to use, which it will push to `models_project` it depends on.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: If you use a class (a driver) in a project, say `models_project`, you must declare the library of it as a dependency of the project. It is because the project uses it directly. I think it's more Slick architectural question not SBT one.

Answer (score 1):

It took me a little while to figure this out too. I have a github project which I used to test this out.

https://github.com/drstevens/slick-testing

I defined a `SlickDriver` trait which allows you to mix in the configured driver along with specific implementations (https://github.com/drstevens/slick-testing/blob/master/src/main/scala/com/daverstevens/sql/SlickDriver.scala)

```
trait SlickDriver {
  val driver: JdbcDriver
}

trait MySqlSlickDriver extends SlickDriver {
  val driver = MySQLDriver
}

trait H2SlickDriver extends SlickDriver {
  val driver = H2Driver
}
```

You can extend `SlickDriver` in a trait in which you define your model. Then you just need to mix in the appropriate SlickDriver at configuration time. Whenever you would normally need to import a driver, instead import the driver which is mixed into the instance of the model you have.

For an example, see [`trait SqlModel`](https://github.com/drstevens/slick-testing/blob/master/src/main/scala/com/daverstevens/sql/SqlModel.scala#L6-L16).

Comment: Thanks for your answer and for taking the time to code the example and push to github. As far as I understand, your solution allow to configure the driver, but doesn't allow for the driver to be injected at runtime. The problem, is that I want to keep the models in an independent repo (and hence, SBT project), that anyone can use (by adding it as an sbt project dependency).

Comment: I coded it up for my own benefit a while ago and just had it on githubs already. Slick only allows you to do so much at runtime. My code allows you to configure the driver at runtime as long as the driver was compiled in as a possible option to be configured. I figured this out based on this Slick mailing list thread. https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/scalaquery/BpPOj_NSOjc